# Should i really repeat all this requirement in every route module file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a larger web app, and have now begun to realise the use of modularising my routes in its own files. But when doing this I notice I have to reapeat alot of requirements... Before i started to move out the routes to its own file I had around 20 required modules in my main app, handling everything from DB to emails...

Many of these modules are used in most of the routes... which mean I have to repeat maybe 15-20 requirements in each route module file.

**Question:** This seems like a alot of repeated code, but maybe this is the righ way to do it?

At least official NPM modules seems to work in this way.

Comment: I realise now that not only requirements has to be duplicated in many files, but also configuration for modules like DB and others... Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Regards database part: you intialise it once. Even if you `import` database access module many times, in reality it will be imported once, and previously created connection will still be available (granted you made it right way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write a module (lets say, `common.js`), which would `require` all of your requirements and return a single object:

```
module.exports = {
  http:        require('http'),
  request:     require('request'),
  async:       require('async'),
  someModule:  require('./someModule')
};
```

Then all you have to do is `require` a single `common` module:

```
var common = require('./common');
common.request.get(...);
common.async.parallel(...);
```

The only inconvenience is that you now have to write `common.` when you want to access these modules.

<strike>You can also use global variables</strike>. Actually using globals is a bad practice, and it's strongly recommended that you don't use them:
[Why are global variables considered bad practice? (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635136/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-node-js) 
[Why are globals bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246284/why-are-globals-bad)

Comment: Nice idea! 
Now I at least know that required modules are cached, and not "processed" multiple times... and that was my biggest concern, rather than the problem of manually writing (copy-paste) these requirements in every file.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about caching. This is what I forgot to mention about :)